# How can one replace bitmap (image) inside exe?

Tags: ida, ollydbg, decompilation, decompile

I have an application (something like a text editor) that has a background image. 
I understand how to replace text in exe file, but what about image? 
I wonder how difficult and what is the way to replace such image using etc ollydbg, IDA?

Comment: There are Several ready made resource editors for example look for Resource hacker byagnus johnson

Comment: I see I can modify the icon of the executable, but no more than that.

Comment: Is this a Windows executable?

Comment: Yes, it is a Windows executable. It is also linked to bunch of dlls.

Comment: I understand it is quite a difficult task and I will not get a straight-forward solution. Just theoretically, if you had to do this, how would you go about doing it?

Comment: Can you provide any program as an example?